# Windows 11 - Resetting network configuration after using VPN software

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, windows-11

I have used a VPN client recently, and after using it I am unable to play a game because it crashes when connecting to the game servers. One of the things I'm trying to debug is any changes the VPN software has made to my system that it is not resetting when I've closed it.

So far I've run these commands to attempt to reset the settings:

> (Running in command prompt as admin)
>
> - Type "ipconfig /flushdns" and press Enter.
> - Type "ipconfig /registerdns" and press Enter.
> - Type "ipconfig /release" and press Enter.
> - Type "ipconfig /renew" and press Enter.
> - Type "netsh winsock reset" and press Enter.
> - Restart the computer.

What are some other things I can do to debug or check that all the networking settings are correct? I've also tried a clean boot as per [Microsoft's Guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd)

Other debugging notes in case they are helpful:

- The game in question is Call of Duty Modern Warfare III. It works fine on my xbox, but doesn't run on the PC.
- The vpn client I've used is [Fastest VPN](https://fastestvpn.com/download).

Thanks!

Comment: It would appear based on your tests that "Fastest VPN" is not totally compliant with Windows 11. Try completely uninstalling the VPN client and restarting to see if that helps.

Comment: I use Fastest VPN from time to time on Windows 11 and everything works fine. Does the internet work well in general?

Comment: Update: This was a red herring. I had ReWASD installed (it's a controller remapping software), and this was triggering the game's anti cheat system and closing the game.